# How to put the icons in accordion in jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to do is show the default icon in accordion just like in the example in jQuery-ui site.

Example: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#custom-icons

My problem is it won't show only the text I see... I tried my code in jsfiddle I see it but its in the same position as text.

Current output: http://jsfiddle.net/MfegM/1663/

Script:

```
$(function() {
      $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      active:false,
      collapsible:true,
      });
});

$(function() {

$("#accordion").accordion( );

$("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons",

{'header': 'ui-icon-circle-arrow-e', 'headerSelected': 'ui-icon-circle-arrow-s' });
       });
```

My links:

```
<!--CSS Links-->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="elogFiles/images/icon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="elogFiles/css/jquery-ui-1.9.2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="elogFiles/css/animate.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="elogFiles/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="elogFiles/css/style.css" type="text/css" />


<!--Script Links-->
    <script src="elogFiles/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="elogFiles/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="elogFiles/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="elogFiles/js/myScript.js"></script>
```

Comment: what is your style sheet markup? I suspect that you're getting HTTP 404 maybe?

Comment: @user3036342 i posted my links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is absolutely right , all you have to do is add this small CSS to your CSS file

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header{
   padding-left: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using a newer version of jquery and jquery ui. It works straight up on 1.8.3 and ui 1.9.2 with your code exaclty

```
// code is yours - I included it so I could post the fiddle below.    
$("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons",
{
    'header': 'ui-icon-circle-arrow-e',
    'headerSelected': 'ui-icon-circle-arrow-s'
});
```

**EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/MfegM/1664/

Comment: i post my links in my page so u can see it.